# Pulling data from HTML using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to pull the USD exchange rate using Google Apps Script, but I am stuck.

```
function fetchIt() {
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.raffles1.net/currency.asp');
  var pageHTML = page.getContentText();
  var xml = Xml.parse(pageHTML, true);
  var mainTable = xml.getElement().getElement("body").getElement("table").getElement("tr").getElement("td").getElement("table");
  var subTable1 = mainTable.getElements("tr")[4].getElement("td").getElement("Table"); 
}
```

Would like to use the script to pull the data periodically. Is there any other way to obtain the data without going through the HTML structure? I am exploring a generic way to retrieve the exchange rate from multiple websites.

Comment: Xml (old) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml: Deprecated. For new scripts, Please prefer the XmlService instead: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/

Answer (score 0):

Google Finance services within Google Apps Script, can handle exchange rates when you enter currency codes side by side as one stock symbol.  For instance, USD (US Dollar) to GBP (Great Britain Pounds) is called in Google Finance as `FinanceApp.getStockInfo('USDGBP')`.

Try this code as a starting point:

```
 function xchange() {

  var info = FinanceApp.getStockInfo('USDGBP');
  Logger.log('The currency %s is trading at %s', info.symbol, info.average);
  Logger.log(info);
```

Some additional functionality would be to take USD and GBP as inputs separately and concatenate them into the input.

Hope this helps.

Jacob

}